# Build options in a visual studio solution with many projects

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build

Build options like "optimize code" "debug info - none", "no DEBUG constant" are defined on a project level in Visual Studio. In a solution with many projects a build is started with a specific visual studio build configuration that is added in one main project file (as XML).

The buid process also builds all dependency projects (dll's) and I wonder if it is possible to define the options mentioned above the main project file ("globally") or should each dependency project file be edited seperately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you must include all referenced projects as projects in the solution of the build job. Then the build configuration of the build is applied to all projects.

When you do not inlcude all referenced projects as projects in the solution, the build server will build all referenced projects in debug configuration.